# Domain for $(g\circ f)(x)$ to be invertible.

Tags: functions, trigonometry

[Problem](https://i.stack.imgur.com/V9khN.jpg):
If
$ f(x)=sin^2x$ and $g(x)=x-x^2+x^3$, then $(g\circ f)(x)$ is invertible in the interval:

(a) $[0,\frac{π}{2}]$
(b)$[-\frac{π}{4},\frac{π}{4}]$

(c)$[\frac{π}{2},π]$
(d)$[\frac{3π}{4},π]$
***My attempt:***

$\because, R_f\in D_g, $
 $~~~~~~$We know, $g\circ f$ is bijective iff

1. $g$ is surjective:
   Assuming $R_g=\mathbb{R}~$and$~\because g'(x)=2x^2+(1-x)^2>0\implies g~   
   $is a monotonic cubic and $\therefore,$ surjective.
2. $f$ is injective: $\implies x \in [\frac{nπ}{2},\frac{(n+1)π}{2}], n\in\mathbb{Z}\\$
   ($\because f$ needs to be monotonic)

I am not sure of this solution.
I would appreciate if anyone can check this and/or provide alternate solution.
(Answer could be multiple- correct. Unfortunately I don't have key.)

Comment: It would appear to be invertible on both $c,d$ as it there strictly decreases. "Surjectivity" is ill-defined when you have not given us a codomain

Comment: @FShrike Even I have the same problem with the question regarding its surjection.

Answer (score 1):

Given $f(x)=\sin^2x$ and $g(x)=x-x^2+x^3$
$$\implies g\circ f(x)=sinx-sin²x+sin^3x=h(x) (say)$$
Now h(x) is invertible iff. it is injective (i. e. every output has unique input) .So it is enough to check it's monotonicity over the following intervals.

Since it's differentiable $$h'(x)=cosx-2sinxcosx+3sin^2xcosx$$

Therefore $h'(x)<0$ for all $x\in[π/2,π]$.

Hence the answer is C and D . I think.

Comment: I think you mistook gof(x) for fog(x). Could you check it.

Comment: Oh yes... let me rectify

Comment: Your method is perfect except h(x) is also monotonic over $[0, \frac{π}{2}]$. So Option A qualifies as well.